# How to create DLQ configuration for per topic?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I using spring cloud stream kafka and wanted to have DLQ setup for all consumer queue , it should be configuration based means I should be able to create DLQ through application.yml file for springboot project.

Any lead would be helpful at this moment

I tried below

```
     listener-in-0:
      destination: queueName
      group: group1
      contentType: application/json
      listener:
        ack-mode: manual
        sync: true
      retry-limit: 5
      retry-wait: 1
      enableDlq: true
```